# Underlining text input with border: none

Tags: html, css

I am trying to underline the input box (as shown in image 1) which has no borders.

What I want:

[image: What I want]

What I have:

[image: What I have]

[image: My code]

Can you please advice? Thanks.

Comment: In future please post code, preferably in a runnable snippet with enough context to demonstrate the issue, rather than pictures of code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
border-bottom: 2px;
```

I think this is what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

`border: none` sets the border-style to none for all sides; you need to override that by setting the specific style `solid` to the bottom border:

```css
body {background-color: #CCC}

input {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  border-bottom: 2px;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  border-bottom-color: white;
  /* Or combine the above:   border-bottom: 2px solid white */
}
```

```html
<input>
```